# How to configure the SDK with Makefile Project on VS?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I would like to develop on a C project with Visual Studio. The project already exists and has a `Makefile`. In other words I initially have something like this:

```
.
├── bar.c
├── bar.h
├── foo.c
├── Makefile
└── test
    └── test_foo.c
```

So I created a `Makefile Project` form the new project wizard. Unfortunately the Intellisense doesn't find links to standard libraries.

The project properties is pretty empty and I cannot really configure anything.

How should I configure VS to get Intellisense working?

My project has:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: When you say **the project already exists** did you mean as a vcxproj file or you have a bunch of c files and a makefile?

Comment: @cup I have edited my question with the missing information

Comment: Maybe best to create a new, empty, project and then move/copy the files to the created project directory and then choose Add to add the files to your project. This allows you to set-up the project as you need (e.g. a Windows or Console application). Following a first time compilation the intellisense will work.